gcc issues incompatible pointer types warning
In C, I need a function to return a void * via one of its arguments. Assume that there's a database which holds pointers to any type of data. Once the user stores the pointers and in other parts of the program the pointers are required to be retrieved. The problem is that the pointers are of different types. Let's begin with an example:
#include <stdio.h>

#define _countof(ar) (sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]))

int count;
void *data[10];

int retrieve(int i, void **p2) {
    if (i < 0 || i > count) return -1;
    *p2 = data[i];
    return 0;
}

int save(void *p) {
    if (count == _countof(data)) return -1;
    data[count++] = p;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 10;
    float f = 10.5;
    save(&n);
    save(&f);
    int *pn;
    retrieve(0, &pn);
    printf("%d\n", *pn);
    float *pf;
    retrieve(1, &pf);
    printf("%g\n", *pf);
    return 0;
}

In the code, the compiler issues the following warnings:
2.c: In function ‘main’:
2.c:26:15: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘retrieve’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   26 |   retrieve(0, &pn);
      |               ^~~
      |               |
      |               int **
2.c:8:28: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
    8 | int retrieve(int i, void **p2) {
      |                     ~~~~~~~^~
2.c:29:15: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘retrieve’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   29 |   retrieve(1, &pf);
      |               ^~~
      |               |
      |               float **
2.c:8:28: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘float **’
    8 | int retrieve(int i, void **p2) {
      |                     ~~~~~~~^~

Note that in calling save function there's no problem. Indeed we use void pointers to be treated as pointers to any type of data. But this is not true for **.
How can I avoid getting this warning? Please don't suggest casting or any other workarounds. I need a solution, please. Why can't void ** be replaced with type ** while void * can be replaced with type *?!
update
Thanks to all of you for replying. Result is that I should use void * instead of void ** and cast in the called function.

Your _countof doesn't work on pointers and an int** or float** is not compatible with a void**.

I didn't use _countof for any pointer in the code. if int ** is not compatible with void **, why int * is compatible with void *?!

Despite the similarity of apperance, a "pointer to void" is a different and unrelated type to a "pointer to pointer to void" Why do you consider a cast a workaround when you are trying to force a conversion that the language does not do implicitly? Apparently, the only answer that fits your specification is to disable the warning in your compiler. I wouldn't suggest that, but you could check your compiler documentation for a way to do that.

For your why, C specifically allows for pointer conversions to & from void *'s. Neither an int ** or a void ** is a void *, so that allowance doesn't apply.

No, I don't suggest it too. Instead, I like to know the source of the warning. A variable which holds a location of the memory regardless of the type of the variable which is stored in the location is called a void pointer. A void pointer is just a pointer without concentrating of what it points to. A void **, logically holds a variable which points to a pointer which type may be ignored. So why int ** should not be compatible with void **?!

@AviBerger I get what you say, but the prototype if be void ** instead of void *, causes the programmer not to confuse, and know that they should pass variable with the nature of being ** instead of *.

Even an int** (or float**) is convertible to a void* (but not void**) so you could make it simpler to just return the stored void*. push/pop example

Oh I see! But let me know how can I inform the callers of the function how to use it? How can I inform them that the pointer they're passing to the function should by of type "type **" not of type "type *"? Is there a way?

The pointer they pass to retrieve() should not be a type **, unless type is void.  If type is something else then retrieve() cannot do its job properly.  At least not with its current signature and without a lot of extra data and code.  But if it returns the stored void * instead of writing it through a pointer then the caller already knows how to perform the appropriate conversion.  This is what @Ted was suggesting.

Hmm, I mean they may mistake and send argument as type * instead of type ** if I prototype the function and void * instead of void **.

I think the cleanest option is what @JohnBollinger suggested in his comment: have restore() return a void * instead of trying to use an output parameter. It best avoids all these issues of proper casting, type conversion, and clarity of intent.

It's just a sample code to discuss on the problem, not going to escape it, going to find a solution for it.

Think of it as follows.
void* kind of means "something". You can pass any pointer argument to a void pointer parameter. But a void** means "pointer to something" and not "something" itself. So passing an int** to a void** means passing a pointer (to an integer pointer) to a pointer pointing to something.
You can get rid of this by using this known "something" type instead of "pointer to something".
int retrieve(int i, void *p2);

But still, you need to cast to void** in the function implementation because else you would dereference a void pointer.
int retrieve(int i, void *p2) {
    if (i < 0 || i > count) return -1;
    *(void**)p2 = data[i];
    return 0;
}

EDIT: As @john-bollinger stated correctly, this code violates the strict aliasing rule. You can either disable strict aliasing in your compiler or use a union to get around this possibly undefined behaviour. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/14794107 for more information.

I see, but if p2 is not really a pointer to a pointer to a variable of any type, the compiler won't check it and this cast will be illegal. If I prototype the function as void **, the user realize that they should pass a pointer to a pointer to the type and won't mistakenly pass type *.

@hamidi You are asking How can I avoid getting this warning?. It is either  with_static_ type checking, where you write all function for all possible combinations for types, or type erase with void * sacrificing exactly type checking.

This will avoid the diagnostic, but it does not solve the actual problem at all.  The primary issue is that accessing an int * via an lvalue of type void * (i.e. *(void**)p2) violates the strict aliasing rule and therefore has undefined behavior.  This is not safe even if int * and void * have the same representation.

The alternative to type erasure by making retrive getting a void * argument as presented in the other answer is to write every overload of the retrieve function for every required type.
int retrieve_int(int i, int **p2) {
    if (i < 0 || i > count) return -1;
    *p2 = data[i];
    return 0;
}
int retrieve_float(int i, float **p2) {
    if (i < 0 || i > count) return -1;
    *p2 = data[i];
    return 0;
}
/* etc. */

For a simple dispatch, you can overload the types using macro and _Generic.
C programming language does not have templates like in C++, so you have to write all combinations.
The alternative is also to just silence the warning retrieve(0, (void**)&pn);.
Note that, technically, your code is invalid. You can't assign to a int * pointer using void ** handle. Consider instead returning a void * pointer and assigning the exit code by a pointer. This similarly type erases, as anyway you erase the types at assignment.
void *retrieve(int i, int *err) {
    if (i < 0 || i > count) { *err = -1; return 0; }
    *err = 0;
    return data[i];
}


The first method is not practical, because the types are up to the users and can't be identified at compile time. The second is a solution, other than more than one things are there to be returned. Thanks all.

Casting the argument at the point of the call is no better than the other answer's alternative of whitewashing the argument's actual data type and casting at the point of access.  Both produce strict-aliasing violations and are therefore unsafe, even though the compiler probably will not warn.  The type-generic approach could work if the types that must be supported are known in advance, but even then I don't see anything to recommend it over the last alternative, returning the pointer.
